# How to make IQueryable reusable and chainable?

Tags: entity-framework, iqueryable

I think I'm a bit confused here.

I have some repositories and services on my EF project. I want to be able to page any of my models with IQueryable.

My repository contains a method that returns IQueryable:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetQuery()
{
    return EntitySet;
}
```

I also have a query object that I intend to use for reusable queries. It's something like this:

```
public static class CarQuery 
{
    public static IQueryable<Car> RegisteredCars(this IQueryable<car> car, int userId)
    {
        return car.Where(r => r.RegisteredUser.UserId == userId);
    }

    public static IQueryable<car> WithStockAvailability(this IQueryable<car> car, bool isAvailable)
    {
        return car.Where(r => r.IsInStock == isAvailable);
    }
}
```

And I am making use of it in my service layer like so:

```
public IEnumerable<Car> GetUserRegisteredCarsInStock(int userId, int? pageNumber, int? pageSize)
{
    var query = _repository.GetQuery(); 

    query = query.RegisteredCars(userId);
    query = query.WithStockAvailability(true);


    if (pageSize.HasValue && pageNumber.HasValue)
    {
        return .OrderByDescending(r => r.carId) // for some reason if I don't have the order, the query fails
                .Skip(pageNumber.Value * pageSize.Value)
                .Take(pageSize.Value);
    }

    return query.ToList();
}
```

But I don't think I am doing this right. Particularly this line:

```
    query = query.RegisteredCars(userId);
    query = query.WithStockAvailability(true);
```

How do I make this look like this:

```
    query.RegisteredCars(userId)
       .WithStockAvailability(true)
       .Page(pageNumber, pageSize);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line should work, as long as you have created the `Page` extension method.

You can modify the `Page` method to include an order by clause like this:

```
 public static IQueryable<T> Page<T, TKey>(this IQueryable<T> source,
     Expression<Func<T, TKey>> orderExpression, 
     int pageNumber, int pageSize)
 {
    return source.OrderBy(orderExpression)
                 .Skip(pageNumber * pageSize)
                  .Take(pageSize);
 }
```

You call the method like this:

```
query = query.Page(r => r.CarId, pageNumber, pageSize);
```

Comment: Hi - I've already tried this - I get a `Skip is only applicable to OrderableEntities, and Order should be above skip` or something similar error, and I can't put an order there because when I do `source.OrderBy(r => r.` that doesn't contain any entity `Car` properties at all, so I am stuck there.

Comment: @LocustHorde - I modified the Page method to include an order by clause.

Answer (score 1):

You have already done the first two.

```
IQueryable<car> query = _repository.GetQuery()
                                   .RegisteredCars(userId)
                                   .WithStockAvailability(true);
```

Paging just needs a generic extension function, which takes an [ordered query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb340178(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static IQueryable<T> Paging(this IOrderedQueryable<T> query, 
                                   int? pageSize,
                                   int? pageNumber)
{
    if (pageSize.HasValue && pageNumber.HasValue)
    {
        return query.Skip(pageNumber.Value * pageSize.Value)
                    .Take(pageSize.Value);
    }

    return query;
}
```

So now you can chain the whole thing:

```
IQueryable<car> query = _repository.GetQuery()
                                   .RegisteredCars(userId)
                                   .WithStockAvailability(true)
                                   .OrderByDescending(c => c.carId)
                                   .Paging(pageSize, pageNumber);
```

Comment: Hi, I mentioned this in the comment below, but when I do the `cars.OrderBy(r => r.carId)` the compiler complains that carId is unknown. Also, for the first two, I can chain them now! I am not sure why it didn't work earlier, but, thanks!

Comment: the order by with `IQueryable<car>` works, I was asking if there was one place, in generic repo, where I can put paging, as I will need to have that same code for almost all my entities. So, in `IQueryable<T>`.. here obviously I'm guessing I will need to do `where T : BaseObject` and have the id in the BaseObject? There's no other way right?

Comment: ok I understand the question now. Changed to a generic extension function.